# Figure at the top, caption at the bottom of the page

Tags: floats, captions

Can place figure at the top of the page, and caption at the bottom?

This is example when i moved caption down, but i want to "stick" it to the bottom.

Figure will be resized to width=1\textwidth, and will occupy 1/3 page height.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{
skip=4cm  % \vfill ?
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics [width=1\textwidth]{test}

\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This id desired output:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTjqy.png]

Comment: Please tell us more about the intended layout. E.g., will this `figure` occupy an entire page?

Comment: So there will be text between the figure and the caption that does not form part of the figure and should naturally flow around it? Do you have lots of other floats floating around before this page and/or after?

Comment: @werner there will be no text between figure and caption. I wanted to put an figure and caption in full page float. Please take look at the image above. I have no clue how :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX doesn't directly support this, but despite rumours to the contrary it doesn't arbitrarily separate floats so with a bit of care you can put the image in a top float and the caption in a bottom float.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics [width=1\textwidth]{test}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\def\x{Some text to fill up some space. }
\def\y{\x\x\x Red green yellow blue \x\x
\x\x\x Red green yellow blue \x\x}

\y\y\y\y

\x\y\x\y\x\y\x\y

Apple orange pear \x\y\x\y\x\y\x\y
Apple orange pear \x\y\x\y\x\y\x\y


\end{document}
```

in an automated workflow where you are not reading the document each time you could set a `\label` in each of the floats and generate an error if the `\pageref` are not the same.

---

Or as clarified in commens perhaps you want the float to take a full page so:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics [width=\textwidth]{test}


\vfill
\caption{A figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\def\x{Some text to fill up some space. }
\def\y{\x\x\x Red green yellow blue \x\x
\x\x\x Red green yellow blue \x\x}

\y\y\y\y

\x\y\x\y\x\y\x\y

Apple orange pear \x\y\x\y\x\y\x\y
Apple orange pear \x\y\x\y\x\y\x\y


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not solve my problem. http://i.stack.imgur.com/xTjqy.png

Comment: @ReRunner you added your example later: the text of your question seems to imply you want what I show here with image above the body text and caption in an insert at the bottom. However the required result that you  added later is completely different simply a full page float witgh no body text on the page, is that what you want (it's a lot easier if that is what you want:-)

Comment: @ReRunner see both of the comments under your question from Mico and Werner were asking for clarification on exactly this point.

Comment: yes full page float witgh no body text /excert caption :)/ on the page is that's what i'm looking for, but it's still to complicated for me :/

Comment: @ReRunner updated answer